# I posted this inspiring excerpt share with everyone

Tags: phrase-usage

Is "I posted this inspiring excerpt share with everyone" correct in grammar?  Should it be "I posted this inspiring excerpt **to** share with everyone"?

> Sam Harris retweeted:  I recently read Lee Smolin's "Einstein's Unfinished Revolution" in preparation for my conversation with him for my audio series. I was so moved by the epilogue, **I posted this inspiring excerpt share with everyone**. Enjoy!

Comment: Either _to share_, or the instruction _Share with everyone!_ as a new sentence.

Comment: Thank you. Is "share" here a verb? Or a noun?

Comment: It's a verb. Harris wanted the quotation _to be shared_ with everyone.